# Find all distinct isomorphisms...

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Find all distinct isomorphisms $\sigma$ of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}})$ in a subfield of $\mathbb {\bar Q}$ such that $\sigma(a) = a$ for all $a \in \mathbb Q$.

I was only able to find the irreducible polynomial (I don't even know if it's necessary) very lost here.

We know that $\alpha =\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}} \to \alpha^2 = 1 + \sqrt{2}$.

Then.

$(\alpha^2 -1)^2 = 2$.

$\alpha^4 – 2\alpha^2 – 1 \to  x^4 – 2x^2 – 1$.

I also know that.

A field $F$ is algebraically closed if every nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$ has a zero
in $F$.

But I'm confused about the isomorphism part.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There are infinitely many rational numbers, so there's no way the field would be finite. I removed the inappropriate tag.

Comment: The automorphism $\sigma$ is fully determined after you know what $\sigma(\alpha)$ is. The image $\sigma(\alpha)$ has to be a zero of $x^4-2x^2-1$. How many of those zeros belong to the field $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2372584/11619). But the way you worded the question suggests that any isomorphism between $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and possibly some other subfield of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ should be included. That changes the game a bit in the sense that it is not required that $\sigma(\alpha)$ should be an element of $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha)$. In that case all you need to do is to prove that $x^4-2x^2-1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q}$ and find all its zeros. You can then scratch the last sentence of my second comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you're right about $x^4-2x^2-1$ being irreducible. (If it were reducible, we would get fewer isomorphisms, because there'd be, in this case only $2$ (we can see there's no rational root), roots to permute.)

Let the zeros be $\alpha,\beta, \gamma ,\delta $.

There's an isomorphism between $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ sending $\alpha \to\beta$.

And there are two more.  Plus the identity,  making $4$.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^4-x^2-1$, then $i\alpha$, $-\alpha$, and $-i\alpha$ certainly aren't.

Comment: Why not?  That $-\alpha $ is would appear obvious.   The other two less so.  @GerryMyerson

Comment: I see.  I made a mistake.   I actually thought that was a general fact.   @GerryMyerson

Comment: Sorry, you're right about $-\alpha$, but the others had to go.

Comment: Yeah,  thanks @GerryMyerson.  Funny I thought that.